# Humhub: “Index is under processing now”

Tags: caching

After solve the **"failed to open stream: Too many open files"** error. I had new problems to login on Humhub.

I have seen in my log file (/humhub/protected/runtime/application.log) the following error:

"Next exception 'Zend_Search_Lucene_Exception' with message 'Index is under processing now' in /protected/vendors/Zend/Search/Lucene.php:297"

Comment: I don't understand, is this a question or an answer, there is a mechanism to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution was: You need only to rename the following folders:**
- "/humhub/protected/runtime/cache/" 
- "/humhub/protected/runtime/searchdb/"

And then create them new with the same name. So that we have the same folders but this time empty.